# php Mysql quotation mark error

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $sql= 'select employee.id AS ID,CONCAT(employee.fname," ",employee.lname) AS Name, IF(loan.status= "unpaid",loan.installment,0) AS Loan where employee.user = "$name"';
```

This doesn't show the result from the table. because this query is showing no match . I think putting "$name" in double quote is the error.

```
   $sql= "select employee.id AS ID,CONCAT(employee.fname," ",employee.lname) AS Name, IF(loan.status= 'unpaid',loan.installment,0) AS Loan where employee.user = '$name'"
```

in this case putting 'unpaid' in single quote doesn't show result for this column

i tried 
employee.user = ''' $name'''
employee.user = "'$name'"
none of these work.. please help

Comment: This question isn't clear. What errors do you get? *How* is this code not working? What is the value of `$name`? Where is it defined? It also looks like you are wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: $name = $_SESSION['id']

Comment: $sql= 'select employee.id AS ID,CONCAT(employee.fname," ",employee.lname) AS Name, IF(loan.status= "unpaid",loan.installment,0) AS Loan where employee.user = "$name"';  this doesn't show the result from the table ... But shows no error... employee.user = ' "$name" ' gives syntax error ...

Comment: Use `mysqli`'s prepared statements with placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes sequence seems correct but 
You missed  the from clause

```
$sql= "select employee.id AS ID,CONCAT(employee.fname, ' ' ,employee.lname) AS Name, 
    IF(loan.status = 'unpaid',loan.installment,0) AS Loan 
    FROM   employee
    INNER JOIN loan on loan.your_key1 = employee.your_key2
    where employee.user = '$name'";
```

You must assign the proper column name to your_key1 and your_key2 for JOIN